# New vertices while rotating an object

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to rotate a few vertices in an object but whenever I try to do so new vertices appear and destroy my object(showed in the video)
https://uupload.ir/view/untitled_nz3x.mp4/
I tried to select all the vertices but whatever I do new vertices happen to creat

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Some actions like canceled extrusions can leave duplicate vertices.  Try selecting all with A and then Alt + M -> Merge by Distance